# General error during semantic analysis: Transform org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroTransformation cannot be run

Tags: eclipse, gradle, groovy, dsl

I am facing the error message when running the Gradle-> Build on groovy file. Can you please help in resolving the issue.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Groovy: compiler error: Missing implementation of resolved method 'abstract java.lang.String getDisablePropertyName()' of abstract class org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.AbstractExtensionMethodCache.
    SongTexGenerator.groovy /src/project2/generator line 1  Java Problem
```

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Groovy:General error during semantic analysis: Transform org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroTransformation cannot be run
    SongDSlParsingGroovyTest.groovy /src/test/java/project2/tests
```

Comment: I ran into this, and in my case the problem appeared to be a mismatch between the Groovy lib that was being pulled in as a transitive dependency by Grails, and the Groovy Compiler version configured in Eclipse. When I changed the Eclipse settings to use the Groovy 3.x compiler, the error went away (my project was using the groovy-3.0.7.jar library, FWIW).  YMMV, HTH.